# What's the difference between BufferingStarted and PlaybackSession.BufferingStarted

Tags: uwp, media-player

I'm using UWP `MediaPlayerElement`, and set

```
var mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
viuMediaPlayer.SetMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
mediaPlayer.BufferingStarted += MediaPlayer_BufferingStarted;
mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.BufferingStarted += PlaybackSession_BufferingStarted;
```

When using `BufferingStarted` event, I found this two both have buffer start event.
Simalarly for events like `PlaybackStateChanged` and others.

What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This duplication is actually caused by the fact that these "duplicated" `MediaPlayer` events are now deprecated. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.bufferingstarted) for the `BufferingStarted` event for example:

> **MediaPlayer.BufferingStarted** may be altered or unavailable after
>   Windows 10, version 1607. **Instead, use the MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession**
>   property to get a MediaPlaybackSession object and then use the
>   **MediaPlaybackSession.BufferingStarted event**.

So you can safely use `MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession` instead and stay on the safe side with future updates.